# Mobile Menu Flashes up After Window Re-sizing (CSS & JS issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Scenario**

I have a mobile menu that shows when the window is below 736px.  There is a javascript toggle on this menu that adds and removes a CSS class that shows the mobile menu ul (and of course the child li items).

When you re-size the window the CSS media query swaps out the desktop menu for the separate mobile menu and the toggle works as planned.

**Problem**

When I re-size the window and then open and close the mobile menu it all works fine, when the window is then subsequently re-sized again after this, the mobile ul and li flash up for a second when the window hits the CSS media query break point again (736px).

I don't know how to stop this happening, it really is sending me totally around the bend and I seem to have spent hours on this and I'm getting nowhere.

If anyone can help me on this I would be so grateful.

P.S I don't mind the fact the mobile menu is still there after re-sizing if the mobile menu was left open - this is intended behaviour.  It's when the mobile menu is closed and the window is resized to desktop and then back to mobile again that the flash of the menu is happening.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/aVYGPr

JS

```
var mobileMenuButton = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-button")
var mobileMenuItems = document.getElementById("mobile-nav-menu-items")

// TOGGLE MOBILE MENU
var mobileMenu = false

function toggleMobileMenu() {

    if (mobileMenu === false) {

      mobileMenuItems.classList.remove("mobileMenuInactive")
      mobileMenuItems.classList.add("mobileMenuActive")
      mobileMenuButton.innerHTML = "Close"
      mobileMenu = true

    } else {

      mobileMenuItems.classList.add("mobileMenuInactive")
      mobileMenuItems.classList.remove("mobileMenuActive")
      mobileMenuButton.innerHTML = "Menu"
      mobileMenu = false

    }
}

mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleMobileMenu()
}, false)
```

CSS

```
body, ul {padding: 0; margin: 0}

#main-header {width: 100%; height: 100px;}

/* desktop navigation */
#main-navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo-holder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 66px;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul#nav-menu-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#main-navigation ul li {list-style-type: none;}

#main-navigation ul#nav-menu-items li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
}

#main-navigation ul#nav-menu-items li a:hover {
  color:blue;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#mobile-menu-button, ul#mobile-nav-menu-items {
  display: none;
}

/* --- MOBILE MENU AND DROPDOWN  ---
Below is a separate menu added for mobiles.
*/

@media screen and (max-width : 736px) {

/*  hides desktop menu  */

  ul#nav-menu-items {display: none}

  #mobile-menu-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    min-width: 75px;
    cursor: pointer;}

  ul#mobile-nav-menu-items {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0px;

  }

  ul#mobile-nav-menu-items li {
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }

  ul#mobile-nav-menu-items li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .3s; 
  }

  ul#mobile-nav-menu-items li a:hover {
    color: lightblue;
  }

/* -------- MOBILE CLASSES ADDED WITH JavaScript*/

#mobile-nav-menu-items.mobileMenuActive {
  animation: showMobileMenu .5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes showMobileMenu {
  0% {opacity: 0;transform: scaleY(0);}
  1% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(1);}
  100% {opacity: 1; transform: scaleY(1);}
}

#mobile-nav-menu-items.mobileMenuInactive {
  animation: removeMobileMenu .5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes removeMobileMenu {
  0% {opacity: 1; transform: scaleY(1);}
  99% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(1);}
  100% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(0);}
}

} /*END OF MOBILE MENU STYLING*/
```

HTML

```
<header id="main-header">
<!--   desktop nav -->
  <nav id="main-navigation"> 
    <div id="logo-holder"></div>
    <ul id="nav-menu-items">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-1"><a href="https://www.google.com">News</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-2"><a href="https://www.google.com">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--    mobile nav -->
    <ul id="mobile-nav-menu-items">
      <li class="mobile-menu-item mobile-menu-item-1"><a href="https://www.google.com">News</a></li>
      <li class="mobile-menu-item mobile-menu-item-2"><a href="https://www.google.com">About</a></li>
      <li class="mobile-menu-item mobile-menu-item-3"><a href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--     button for triggering mobile nav -->
    <div id="mobile-menu-button">Menu</div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just removed the code below and it worked, maybe because you are manipulating the same event in your CSS and JS file.

```
@keyframes removeMobileMenu {
  0% {opacity: 1; transform: scaleY(1);}
  99% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(1);}
  100% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(0);}
}
```

Comment: I want the animation to animate out not just disappear, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a rather old question, but since there wasn't a great answer here I thought I'd add one for others searching.

I recently came across this exact same issue and ended up figuring out a pretty good solution to it. I documented it all at https://stevenwoodson.com/blog/solving-animation-layout-flickering-caused-by-css-transitions/ if you're still in need of a fix!

The gist is that the transition needs to be added separately in a different class so you can remove it when you're not actively opening or closing the menu.